# Meaning of verb in infinitive phrases

Tags: grammar, verbs, meaning-in-context

> 1. I took my car to the garage **to have them check the air-conditioner.**
> 2. **To watch Uncle Billy tell this story** is an eye-opening experience.

What is the meaning of the verbs *check* and *tell* in these infinitive phrases?
Are they acting as verbs or another part of speech? Because this is not a simple present tense.

Comment: I would guess *check* and *tell* were subjunctives here.  Personally, I would start the second with "Watching Uncle Billy tell..."

Answer (score 2):

*Check* in the first sentence, and *watch* in the second, are infinitives, that is they are non-finite verb forms. The infinitive is often preceded by the particle *to*, but it is omitted before *check* in the first sentence, where *have* conveys the sense of ‘cause to happen’. Other verbs after which *to* is omitted are *make, see, hear* and *let*.

The second sentence could begin with *Watching*, with little change in meaning, but as Mark says, the infinitive can give the sentence the nature of a general truth.

Comment: So this phrase is a infinitive with causative combination. am i right sir ?  could we call this is a causative phrase structure ? Because i know only simple phrase structure like (to check the air-conditioner.) as well as if there is any other phrase structure . i would like to know them. - thank you

Comment: It matters less what you call it than how you use it.

Answer (score 0):

"To visit Paris is a wonderful experience" vs "Visiting Paris is a wonderful experience" : the meaning is essentially the same, but with a hue : a general truth without connection with time, vs a more empathic act of actually doing.

Comment: Agreed. Where's the answer, by the way?

Comment: The answers seemed obvious :